# In jquery, how can I select a whole item as a text, rather than it's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, dom, variables

lets say I have a

```
<div id="god">
Supertext
</div>
```

I want to assign

```
<div id="god">
Supertext
</div>
```

to a variable

```
.text()
.html()
```

only gets "supertext" as a value.

```
$("#god")
$("#god").clone
```

returns an object

I don't want to wrap the object and get it's html, because it's time consuming.
How can I select the whole item and assign it to a variable in javascript?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [browsers that support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility) you can use the `outerHTML`

```
$("#god")[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Why did you use jQuery for? if you use only native javascript functions, don't use jQuery.

Comment: because the OP used it, and wanted to answer the specific part only.. But you are right.. for the situation in the example code, it doesn't really offer much help.

Comment: Upvoting because support is important.  Did Firefox really only pick up on this in 11?

Comment: @zigg, looks that way.. i doubt they would have wrong info on their own website (*but yes.. quite delayed support..*)..

Comment: can you edit your answer and explain what [0] indexer stands for?

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan, it is the same as doing [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/). It returns the actual DOM element, instead of a jQuery object. This way we can access the DOM properties like outerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use jQuery selectors, just to use native javascript functions!**

```
document.getElementById('#god').outerHTML
```